# Is it grammatically correct to put both of related nouns in plural form?

Tags: nouns, plural-forms, singular-vs-plural

Is it grammatically correct to put both of related nouns in plural form? Like:

- card**s** database**s** / database**s** of card**s**
- word**s** variation**s** / variation**s** of word**s**
- etc

Comment: The possible duplicate is about s's at then end of nouns, but that's about as close as it gets, and the answer doesn't really answer either part of this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both of your examples, the first form is called a compound noun: the first noun modifies the second noun, in the same way that an adjective would. When you use a compound noun, the modifying noun is never pluralized.

> card databases
>   word variations

In the second form, you are using a genitive form, indicated by the word **of**. With the genitive, you use the plural for the first word **if there is more than one** of the item that the first word describes. If there is only one of it, you use the singular form even if there are many items described by the second word.

> a database of cards
>   two databases of cards.